# Havdalah: mistake in the bracha

Tags: halacha, blessing, mistakes, havdalah

If a person saying havdalah began the last bracha (benediction) without mentioning *sheim umalchus* (God's name and dominion) i.e. he said ברוך אתה השם המבדיל בין קודש לחול וכו׳, skipping אלוקינו מלך העולם, can that bracha be considered *samuch lichaverta*, connected to the previous, so as to be able to say the start doesn't matter after the fact, and people listening fulfilled the obligation of havdalah?

Comment: [Ketubot 8a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=15&daf=8&format=pdf)

Comment: @AA- are you saying that the fact that it has a pesicha at all means that it is obviously not considered smucha lichaverta?

Comment: @user6591 I would think he means that since the *beracha* before it is a *beracha ketzara* (short *beracha* - no *chasima*), it would require a proper *pesicha*.